# I don't exactly understand this part of code

Tags: python, math, exponent

I don't understand what the code does it works im happy but i wanna understand what is it doing , im total beginner ...

```py
def raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num):
    result = 1
    for ind in range(pow_num):
        result = result * base_num
    return result
```

I don't understand this part of code   python

```
for ind in range(pow_num):
    result = result * base_num
```

Comment: Your question would be better phrased if you could pick on a part of the function to ask about.

Comment: This function is a pretty standard type thing in python. You need to point out the part that is confusing you. Also, why are you not using the built in math.pow() function?

Comment: 2^3 = 2 *2*2. here base_num=2 and pow_num=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the code:

```
for ind in range(pow_num):
    result = result * base_num
```

is just a `for` loop where `ind` is not actually used inside the loop.

Often such a loop would be written:

```
for _ in range(pow_num):
    result = result * base_num
```

using an underscore to mean a variable that is not used.

The `range(pow_num)` means that the loop will go round `pow_num` times.

The calculation: `result = result * base_num` just keeps multiplying by `base_num`, so eventually the power is calculated as others have pointed out.

For example, calling `raise_to_power(2, 3)` would mean that `result` would start at `1` and be successively multiplied by `2` a total of `3` times:

```
result = 1
result = 2
result = 4
result = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a power function `raise_to_power(a,b)` it will give you `a` to power `b` `(a^b)`.
It will multiply a , b times.  `raise_to_power(a,b) = a*a......*a`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand a code is to Particularize it.

```
def raise_to_power(4, 3):   # base_num = 4 , power_num = 3   
result = 1                  
for ind in range(3):
    result = result * 4
return result
```

So **result** = 1 initially. Then a loop is run 3 times (power_num times). In that loop, the value of **result** is updated. So **result** becomes its previous value (here 1) multiplied by the **base_num** i.e. 4. So result=4

In second iteration, again **result** is updated to **result** = 4 x 4 = 16
In third and final (here 3 iterations), result becomes **result** = 16 x 4 = 64

So overall this function is calculating the **pow_num** power of **base_num**

Answer (score 0):

The first line states the function raise_to_power with two variables, base_num and pow_num.

The next line is a starting point (1). The function should only return integers (numbers that are not decimals) and not a float (numbers that contain decimals). Any number times 1 is itself which is important to know for this code.

The next line proposes a qualified statement (when this happens... do that). Here when you have a pow_num (exponent). 
It will multiply the base_num by itself for pow_num of times.

This function calculates the base_num ^ pow_num.

Answer (score 0):

well, all it is really doing is taking the base number and putting it to the power of something then returning the result so for example

say the base_num is 5 and pow_num is 3. You have to set the result to 1 to start off because obviously if you set it to 0 since its multiplication your answer would always be 0.

So, then it takes your base_num loops through and multiplies it the number of times equal to your pow_num.

In this case it would take your 5 multiply it by the result which is 1 so you would be left with 5 which is what you want the base_num to be then it takes that 5 and multiplies it the number of times you selected for your power_num which was 3 so it goes 5*5*5 to get your a result of 125 which is then returned so you can do whatever you want with